# Knockoutjs foreach binding doesn't update <ol> numbers in IE

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I include a foreach binding of my observableArray twice on my page, the numbers on the ordered list all show 1 when adding objects to the array

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: Participants">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: email"> </span>          
    </li>                         
</ol>
```

and it shows as follows:

```
1. test1@test.com

1. test2@test.com
```

When I hide the div containing the ol and show it back, the numbers get updated and show the correct values

If the foreach binding is included only once, everything works fine and the numbers get updated while I am adding to the array.

```
1. test1@test.com

2. test2@test.com
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Edit: This actually happens only in IE when the second div is hidden
here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem http://jsfiddle.net/c4Hc8/

Comment: ol numbers are put there by your browser. if `1` is repeated it must mean you have 2 `ol` elements with a single `li` inside. (note: ive never used knockout)

Comment: [Sigh] I can't duplicate this issue with Knockout, maybe you can show more code?  If not, please close this issue.

Comment: Try it in another browser and see if the problem persists

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was able to isolate the display:none of the second div as the culprit. This happens now only in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly believe now that this is a bug in Knockoutjs.

For anyone experiencing the same issue, I fixed this by replacing `display:none;` of my div with `visibility:hidden;`

The following fiddle shows that the numbers in the `<ol>` are updated correctly with this fix http://jsfiddle.net/c4Hc8/1/